# How to find the row from which drag has started QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I was working on QTableView and I want to achieve drag and drop on it.
The way I want it is:
When I drag, I want to take out the row which is to be dragged and place an empty place holder there, this is how I have reimplemented dragEnterEvent:

```
void dragEnterEvent ( QDragEnterEvent * event )
{
    if( event->source() == this )
    {
        // Get the row to be dragged

        int mItemDraggedRowPosition = rowAt( event->pos().y() );

        auto currentModel = model();

        auto standardModel = boost::polymorphic_cast< QStandardItemModel *>( currentModel );

        // Take out the dragged row
        QList<QStandardItem *> mDraggedItem = standardModel->takeRow ( ( mItemDraggedRowPosition ) );

        // Insert an empty row there
        standardModel->insertRow( ( mItemDraggedRowPosition ), new QStandardItem() );
        }

        event->accept();
    }
}
```

Now the problem I am facing here is the row number which I am getting is incorrect some times.

Am I not doing it correctly .?
Is there any alternative way to find out the row from which the drag was started,
seems like the way I am trying to get it:

int mItemDraggedRowPosition = rowAt( event->pos().y() );

does not return correct value always.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, but now I tried your code with event filter and all my rows numbers was correct. You said that you want `find out the row from which the drag was started`, but dragEnterEvent shows you event when user enter widget to drag. `The QDragEnterEvent class provides an event which is sent to a widget when a drag and drop action enters it.`

Comment: thanks again for investing your time,
It comes correctly to me as well for most of the time, BUT when I enter into drag very close to the joining area of 2 rows I ends up with the row towards which I start the drag ( I used debug messages to make that out ), were you getting the correct row number with my code ..?.
Also is there a way you know of with which I can tell Qt that this is the number of pixels for which if I drag then only it will qualify for drag event..?

Comment: I finally reproduced problem and updated my answer. It is exactly my code which I think work without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I finally reproduced problem and I got incorrect values too (drag very close to the joining area of 2 rows). So I solved this issue with next event filter:

```
ui->tableView->setDragEnabled(true);//somewhere in constructor
ui->tableView->setAcceptDrops(true);
//...
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == ui->tableView->viewport() && event->type() == QEvent::DragEnter)
    {
         QDragEnterEvent * e = static_cast<QDragEnterEvent *>(event);
         qDebug( ) << ui->tableView->rowAt(e->pos().y());
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

To use `eventFilter` you should also:

```
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);//in header
```

and

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);//in constructor
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally ended up overriding "mousePressEvent" and saving the start position there.
I use the same saved position in "dragEnterEvent".
This one works perfectly for me.

```
void
PrePressView::TableWidget::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * inEvent )
{
    if ( inEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton )
    {
        int rowToMove = rowAt( inEvent->y() );
    }
}
```